# How to remove a specific string from list<strings>

Tags: c#

I've got a list of strings called xyz the string has this structure iii//abcd, iii//efg. how can I loop through this list and remove only iii// ?
I have tried this but it remove everything. thanks

```
string mystring = "iii//";
xyz.RemoveAll(x=> x.Split ('//')[0].ToString().Equals (mystring));
```

Comment: Do want to remove "iii//" from each string in the list or remove all strings that start with "iii//"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Removing all the strings who start with `iii//`:

```
xyz.RemoveAll(x => x.StartsWith(@"iii//"));
```

Removing the `iii//` from all strings:

```
var newList = xyz.Select(x => x.Replace(@"iii//", string.Empty)).ToList();
```

Comment: remove only iii// from all strings

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also which will remove the string from list if it starts with "iii/" other wise not.

```
      string mystring = "iii//";
      xyz.RemoveAll(x=>x.StartsWith(mystring));
```

Comment: this removed everything

Comment: Does your main list contains 'iii//' for all members if so then it will remove all the strings but what you want to do if a member contains 'iii//' then you want to remove that member or just replace the 'iii/' part member will not be deleted

Comment: I want to remove or replace 'iii/' from anywhere in string start or end, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe OP wants something to remove `iii//` from all strings:

```
string prefix = "iii///";
List<string> xyz = ...;
var result = xyz.Select(x => x.Substring(prefix.Length)).ToList();
```

*Note:* this of course assumes that each string really starts with `prefix`.